# Strange behavior of PromptForChoice in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

While testing out the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69098394/powershell-promptforchoice-how-to-edit-descriptions) I noticed some inconsistencies in the different versions of PowerShell.

I am using this code, the working version:

```
Clear-Host

$title    = 'Make a Selection'
$question = 'Which Option do you want?'
$Default = -1
$Choices = @(
    [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(
       "&First Choice", "Select First Option")
    [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(
       "&Second Choice", "Select Second Option")
    [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new(
       "&Third Choice", "Select Third Option")
)

<#+--------------------------------------------------------+
  |Note: Choices numbered from ZERO!                       |
  |      If close box selected (X) returns -1              |
  |      $Default is the default choice, i.e. Enter if it  |
  |               is -1 there is no default!               |
  +--------------------------------------------------------+#>

$MultiChoice = 
   $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, $Default)

If ($MultiChoice -gt -1) {

  Switch ($MultiChoice)
  {
      0       {'You selected Option 1'}
      1       {'You selected Option 2'}
      2       {'You selected Option 3'}
      Default {}
  } #End Switch

} #End If

Else  { $Host.UI.WriteLine("User Cancelled Dialog") }
```

The problem is in the ELSE clause. I tried just using the string and using Write-Host and neither sent the string to the console. It would seem that somehow those methods were turned off by the call to $Host.UI?

**Observations:**

**If run in Posershell_ISE:**

You get a dialog box and the $Default setting -1 works.
To output to the terminal after using this you need to use $Host.UI.Writeline() as the standard Write-Host does not work nor does just emitting a string!

**If run in PowerShell CMD or PowerShell Core (7) you get:**

Make a Selection
Which Option do you want?
[F] First Choice  [S] Second Choice  [T] Third Choice  [?] Help (default is "T"):

Even if you enter an invalid choice or just ENTER, even if $Default set to -1, you get reprompted so make sure you offer an EXIT option!

Is this a known bug/behavior or an I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working as expected:

1. PowerShell ISE is a GUI application and PowerShell is a console application. You can see the difference by evaluating `$Host.Name`:

   - PowerShell ISE: `Windows PowerShell ISE Host`
   - PowerShell: `ConsoleHost`

   If you are using `$Host.UI`, you are accessing host specific functions. That's why you get a window when working with PowerShell ISE and console interaction when working with PowerShell.
2. The equivalent of clicking on the <kbd>X</kbd> to close the window is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the console. You will get your `User Cancelled Dialog` message in both cases.
3. Consider the equivalent of giving a wrong choice in PowerShell, to be clicking somewhere else than on the buttons in the window from PowerShell ISE. The dialog will stay open, like you get reprompted in PowerShell.

Except:

The output to your console after cancelling [`PromptForChoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice). To investigate further, you can use the following [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
$MultiChoice = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice('', '', [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&A",""), -1)

$Host.UI.WriteLine("WriteLine")
Write-Host "Write-Host"
Write-Output "Write-Output"
Out-Host -InputObject "Out-Host"
"Out-Default" | Out-Default
```

The problem is not your `else` clause. The output does not work as expected, if a `PromptingException` is thrown in `PromptForChoice` ([source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterfacePromptForChoice.cs#L97)). It is thrown, if you cancel the prompt either by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in PowerShell or by closing the prompt in PowerShell ISE.

My first impression is, that the exception is not handled correctly. So it might be a (not very uncommon) bug.

Comment: Thanks! That will give me something to chew on for a while...LOL